# Calling CMD command line from ReactJS application

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, reactjs, command-line

I have a React Application and I'm looking to run a CMD Command-Line function from a button click.
What is the best way of doing this?

I am able to run the cmd command through a python script of my own however how could I run this python from React as React is hosted on localhost and security permissions limit access to cmd from there.
Should I be looking to set up a python server to host the python script?

Alternatively, I have been looking at Node.js would that be a better way of running this python script and ultimately connect to cmd?

Comment: You need to do it server-side (python, node, java..). You create your function on the server and use a rest api call to trigger it from front end (react).

Comment: So load the python script onto a localhost port and then call cmd from there?

Comment: You can run a lite python webserver with for instance Flask. You set the port on which you want to run it and create an endpoint which runs your script. For example Flask runs on localhost:8080 and your endpoint is ‘/cmd-function’. Then on frontend you execute a http get request to url localhost:8080/cmd-function and your function will be executed

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure a server side and  use the child-process module
`import * as child from 'child_process';` 
then in your function use :
`child.exec("your command line")`

Answer (score 1):

React is working in the browser so it's impossible to directly access command line.

Comment: Yes I know calling it directly is impossible however there must be a way to run a local python script from a localhost react application

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the child-process module
`import * as child from 'child_process';` 
then in your function use :
`child.exec("your command line")`